# Windows Forms Databound Control Accessing Getters For All Properties

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, data-binding

I have several bound controls on a Windows Form that link to properties on another class.  When ANY ONE of the controls' values is changed, ALL bound properties' Getters are accessed.

Class code:

```
Public Class Student

    Private _Name As String
    Public Property Name As String
        Get
            Return _Name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _Name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _Grade As String
    Public Property Grade As String
        Get
            Return _Grade
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _Grade= value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _Age As Integer
    Public Property Age As Integer
        Get
            Return _Age 
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _Age = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Form Code:

```
Public Class Main

    Public ThisStudent As New Student

    Private Sub Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Name_TextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", Me.ThisStudent, "Name")
        Me.Grade_TextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", Me.ThisStudent, "Grade")
        Me.Age_TextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", Me.ThisStudent, "Age")
    End Sub

End Class
```

When I type into the "Name" texbox only, the Getters for Name, Grade, and Age are ALL being accessed (I'm actually not even sure why the Getter is being accessed for "Name" itself, since it should just be Setting the name).  In my actual use-case, the Getters are doing some extra validation, which makes the Databinding VERY slow whenever a control value changes and it then checks the Getters of 30+ other properties that are unrelated, but are bound to entirely different controls.

Is there a way for me to Databind multiple controls to properties in the same object, but only access the properties that are actually bound to that specific control?

Comment: Another approach: do nothing "extra" in the getter, just return value. If you want do some validations do it in the method and call it from correspondent control events.

Answer (score 1):

When you bind to an object and change the value of bound property of a data-bound control, all bound controls will reload their values by default and it calls the getter of the properties.

To stop this behavior, you can to set [`ControlUpdateMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding.controlupdatemode?view=netframework-4.7.2) property of [`Binding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding?view=netframework-4.7.2) class to `Never`:

```
Me.Name_TextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", Me.ThisStudent, "Name") _
    .ControlUpdateMode = ControlUpdateMode.Never
Me.Grade_TextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", Me.ThisStudent, "Grade") _
    .ControlUpdateMode = ControlUpdateMode.Never
Me.Age_TextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", Me.ThisStudent, "Age") _
    .ControlUpdateMode = ControlUpdateMode.Never
```

This way you are saying, never reload `Name_TextBox`, `Grade_TextBox` and `Age_TextBox`.

If for any reason you want to reload value of the data source into control, you can force a control update by calling the [`ReadValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding.readvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2) method on the related `Binding`.

For example to reload all values of `ThisStudent` into the related `TextBox` controls, you can use the following code:

```
BindingContext(ThisStudent).Bindings.Cast(Of Binding) _
    .ToList().ForEach(Sub(x) x.ReadValue())
```

Comment: That was one of the reason where MVVM in Winforms ran out of hands ;)

Comment: This is an interesting approach, I will have to test it out.  Thank you!